# Работа с файлами в С

Tags: c, файлы, циклы

Мне необходимо открывать файлы в программе автоматически.К примеру, у меня есть несколько файлов с именами - 10_04_16.txt,11_04_16.txt,12_04_16.txt и так далее. открыть их по отдельности не проблема, но что если я хочу чтобы программа открывала такие файлы сама, то есть как описать цикл, который бы открывал файлы с такими именами(разница в названии которых только 1 цифра)? Сталкивался ли кто-нибудь с подобной задачей и что посоветуете? P.S. программу пишу на C.

Comment: Для винды - FindFirstFile/FindNextFile позволят перебрать файлы по маске в любом каталоге. Дальше - дело техники.

Answer (score 1):

Например, как-то так:

```
for(int i = 10; i < 20; ++i)
{
    char name[20];
    sprintf(name,"%d_04_16.txt",i);
    FILE * f = fopen(name,"rt");
    if (f) {
        /* ..... */
        fclose(f);
    }
}
```

Comment: я использую это в Си Билдере ХЕ6, и загружаю таким образом файлы автоматически, так вот в компонент Мемо1 загружается только последний файл, а мне нужно чтобы выводились все